# Mocean ad(158212768) - Server response with empty body (no ads) error?

Tags: ios, ads

I am using **mocean's interstitial ad** in my iOS project.

I am able to display dummy ads using dummy **site_id and zone_id.**

But when I replace dummy site_id and zone_id with my own ids, it gives following error -

```
Ad  ad(158212768) - Server response with empty body (no ads) | error: Error Domain=Server response with empty body (no ads) Code=22 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Server response with empty body (no ads) error 22.)"
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ads provider do you use? As far as i know, there are several companies, that use mOcean SDK for iOS for advertisements (YOC Performance, Mojiva).

Possibly, you need to setup `adServerUrl` property of your newly created `MASTAdView` class object. For Mojiva, for example, it must be `@"http://ads.mojiva.com/ad"`. For YOC Performance it is `@"http://ads.mo.yoc-adserver.com/ad"`, but i'm not sure about it.

PS: also, as you wish to aggregate more than one advertiser in you ios app (and want to manage ads displaying for different regions and countries and much more for growing your revenue from application), there is good alternative to AdWhirl - [Epom SDK for iOS](http://epom.com/)